# Formula in table not incrementing when new entry added

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table called Orders and to get the order totals I am using this in a formula;

```
COUNTIF($C$9:C9,[@[Order ID]])>1
```

However, when a new entry is added the C9 doesn't increment and I get an error flag. Is there an alternative way to reference the range that will increment.

Comment: Hard to tell without a data example,  but maybe you want `=COUNTIF([Order ID],[@[Order ID]])>1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the entire formula using structured references, I would suggest:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX([Order ID],1):[@[Order ID]],[@[Order ID]]) >1
```

`INDEX([Order ID],1)` will return the first cell (row 1) in the `[Order ID]` column as the start of the range, so it will remain a fixed reference as it does in your original formula referencing `$C$9`, with the advantage of being able to move the table anyplace and not have to update that hard-coded reference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end

```
COUNTIF($C$9:[@[Order ID]],[@[Order ID]])>1`
```

Comment: Since you are using structured references, consider replacing `C9` with `INDEX([Order ID],1)`and make the entire formula:  `=COUNTIF(INDEX([Order ID],1):[@[Order ID]],[@[Order ID]]) >1`

Comment: OK you can add that as a question but please explain it as well. Thanks.